# let the jquery script detects mouse movement over the swf object?

Tags: jquery, flash

I am facing this problem. i tried to create a function that detect if any mouse movement over the swf object, but i tried, when the cursor is over the swf object, jquery mouseover doesn't return anything.

so any idea to let the jquery script detects mouse movement over the swf object?

P.S. i couldnt edit the swf file.
Regards,

Weijian

Comment: Here you are..
http://jsfiddle.net/WJ___/XSjQr/
even over the iframe will be good,too:)

Comment: you can use ".hover", but until the user clicks the video, it won't do anything

Comment: .hover is just for the moment when the cursor enter the object..what is need is a event can be driven even the mouse is over the swf object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for clicking, but still no luck for mouse movement, since i was using swfoject.js to embed the swf file i guess this issue only happens under swfobject.js. i added in the wmode parameter and now the clicking event swf is working.